# performance monitoring on server

Tags: web-server, monitoring, performance-monitoring

I think the tool name is SARS? I have CPanel host and need to monitor loads and such. What tool and how do I do it?

I'm just wanting to be able to tie in load average with a site randomly not loading and seeing if the two tie in together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `sar`:

> sar - Collect, report, or save system activity information.

This is part of the "sysstat" package.  If you're using Ubuntu, you'd run `apt-get install sysstat` to install it.  On RHEL-derived distros, you'd run `yum install sysstat`.

Answer (score 0):

I think sar will gives you more refined values, which sometime case becomes difficult to debug. There are lot of different linux tools that generates report in more intuitive way. Some are as follows

1. top - it is almost a task manager for linux
2. free - gives you report about system memory usage
3. vmstat - gives you report for memory cpu usage
4. uptime - load avg of the system

you can set cron job collecting report in a single file to generate report/debug later.

If this all above are too much of a mess, you can use some web based tools like [SeaLion](https://sealion.com), [New Relic](http://newrelic.com), [Server Density](http://serverdensity.com) etc. They are very simple to use.